# Validation Rule to make text field mandatory based on picklist value selected

Tags: validation

Validation Rule to make text field mandatory based on picklist value selected.
eg:-
If i had a picklist if i select a "High" then a text box must become required and print a message.

Comment: So, what is your exact question ? have you already tried to write a validation rule ?  Adding more information to the question will help us understand where you are stuck and how we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

As @Samuel asked, it's better if you can give more info. Below is a general solution for you.

`IF(
    AND(
        TEXT(PikListField) = "High", 
        ISBLANK(Your_Text_Field)), True, False
 )`

Give an appropriate error message for the validation.
**UPDATE**
If you have a rich text field it's better to use `LEN ( Your_Rich_Text_Field ) = 0` since it has been reported that `ISBLANK` will return `true` always with `Rich Text Fields` in [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004240&language=en_US)

Comment: This answer will work well. I sometimes use ISPICKVAL(Field_Name__c, "High") instead of the TEXT method. Either is fine.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this. Let me show this with an example where let project__c be a picklist and others be one of the values and if we select "others" then the describe_project__c text field will become compulsary.Validation rule for this will be

```
IF(
AND(
TEXT(project__c) = "Other", 
LEN(describe_project__c) = 0), True, False)
```

I guess this will work for you.

Answer (score -2):

We can assign check if a text field is blank when a certain picklist value is chosen by using below validation rule:

```
ISPICKVAL( reason__c ,"other") && ISBLANK( text_field__c )
```